# Decision-making in small American cities

Tags: united-states, decision-making

In several American cartoon series (namely "The Simpsons" and "South park"), there is a pattern, which appears in many episodes:

1. Some major external event happens (e. g. an important part of the road is broken) or someone has an attractive idea (e. g. build a mono-rail).
2. Citizens of the town are assembled and make a decision on how to react to that event.
3. The officials implement the decision made by the citizens.

I never was to the United States and I'm wondering whether it works that way in real life. After all, these are just cartoons.

In other words: Is it true that in small (up to 100 000 inhabitants) American cities ordinary citizens (i. e. not deputies, not state officials) can propose changes to the policy, which - if approved by the majority - are actually implemented by the officials?

Comment: I would expect that the answer **heavily** depends on a specific municipality. Some have referendums, some don't. Some add big items like this to their election ballots (though usually this is more at the state level).

Comment: Yeah, the constitution doesn't mention cities at all, so the decision making structure will depend on the state and county.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This varies greatly state by state, in oversimplified terms, the top down structure of the US is: 
Federal -> State -> County > City.

I'm pretty sure *The Simpsons* is based on Ancient Athens, most city councils in the United States are more formal, and rigid. At least upon appearance See the first few season of *Weeds* for a more realistic dramatization.

It varies on a state by state basis: depending on who controlled the area when the city was founded, large parts of the US were formerly controlled by: England, France, Spain, and Russia for example. Some states/counties/cities still maintain legacy legal structures, treaties, and other legal baggage from these periods.

However, most cities have a Republican form of government, similar to the relationship between the house of representatives: each geographical area gets a representative, usually sponsorship from one of these people is required to introduce a change in City law, funding,etc.
A mayor is sometimes part of this process, and/or is the deciding factor in the case of 
[City Councils](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_government_in_the_United_States#City_councils)

In California, most cities large and small allow for an individual, or group to gather a certain number of signatures from registered voters, submit them to the council, and after which the elected council votes on yes or no, some require two thirds majority, some a simple, fifty-one percent.

Most cities, large and small, have public online access to these, rather dry and boring meetings. Portland,Oregon, the hometown of *Simpsons* creator Matt Groening, streams their meetings  [Watch](http://www.portlandoregon.gov/28258), believe me, most are about as interesting as counting grains of sand in the desert.

What *The Simpsons* is dramatizing is the tendency of interest groups to bring many members to show support for their agenda, speak before or against said measure, and other elements of a democratic republic.

Answer (score 5):

The form of government is called "Town Meeting", and is a form of government common in many parts of the United States, especially in the New England region (States North of New York State), Upstate New York (The Part of the State that is not New York City), and certain municipalities in New Jersey.  At this point, for the point of funsies mostly, I'd like to point out that between these states there are 11 Springfields, including the  original U.S. Springfield (Mass.) and no less than three separate Springfields in New Jersey alone.

Town Meetings are a form of local Direct Democracy and were started as the form of government that was used by local churches (which often were tied to the town's government prior to the Revolution).  For a non-U.S variation, two Cantons in Switzerland also employ this style of government in local elections though it was more popular back in the earlier days of the nation.  That said, all 50 states in the U.S. have some level of Direct Democratic procedures in government at the State Level, it is lacking in the federal level only.  Back in the early days of the United States, Town Meetings were quite popular in the North East small towns because there wasn't much else to do.  These are typically remote parts of the states where it's a small town and nothing else, so it provided incentive for attendance because they were both fun and you probably had an opinion on the laws being brought to a vote.  And yes, if the town has a budget for a monorail project and the town wants it badly enough, the town can vote on it (They usually don't have a budget for it, and Springfield only did because Burns got hit with a ridiculous fine and they had to spend the money on something.  They also don't rehearse their votes into a choreographed homage to "The Music Man").

Southpark is an example of a Town Hall Meeting (type A.  There's a Type B to come).  Town Hall Meetings differ from Town Meetings in that local issues are usually discussed by the town with the elected body, who are then tasked with coming up with the solution.  As depicted in Southpark, this amounts to a series of scenes where the mayor and the various people who flank her (presumably the council) are just a bunch of Rabble Rousers and she's just barely containing her contempt for the crowd's idiocy of the week and that these people will be asked to vote on her job...  sometimes they're only there to literally repeat "Rabble" to make the point clear.

Another American Series, Parks and Recs, is basically an extended joke about how the only people who show up to Town Hall Meetings are people who hate the proposed ideas.  This is very much a real life thing as any town discussing something controversial is bound to have soundbites from the opposition only... and its only the controversial meetings... most Town Hall meetings are woefully empty and devoid of anyone who cares about anything and the membership of the council with decision making authority is only interested in a select few pet project issues (See King of the Hill, where Hank Hill runs for council to repeal the city's low flow toilet mandates... which were implemented by a bill introduced by the council member who just happens to be the only plumber in town to stock the toilet type in question.  These types of local governments are much more common in the United States and can be found in just about any city, town, or, community of any size (if not, expect the school board or PTA to sub in... Everyone has at least one of these three).

Type B Town Hall Meetings are conducted by National Level government politicians in their constiuency and normally involve explaining the issues before them in Congress and getting their constituents takes.  They typically tend to be a lot of noise over particular issues with pro and con lobbies trying to fill seats with supporters of their particular issue to steer the conversation.  Expect citizens who are angry and actually live in the locality thrusting mail to prove residency and talking about how they voted for the politician and don't support them on this issue either.   These are often the format of Campaign stops and some Presidential debates in Election years, where the politician will answer issue based questions from the crowd.  These are much more susceptible to plant questioners, especially if the candidate is a presidential candidate, especially the Town Hall Debates, where almost all the candidates are selected and given a very formatted question.   It's not even well hidden as enough "members" of the audience break with the question they submitted to the moderators to ask a question the moderator team was not anticipating and is a bit more hard ball to the candidate.

Comment: Since you're drawing on popular culture to explain the various forms of meetings:  *Gilmore Girls* is set in a small town in New England, and frequently features classic New-England-style town meetings.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert:  I didn't include it because I've never seen Gilmore Girls in my life, but thanks for the additional example.   Should also point out but Town Meetings come up a lot in Horror Movies in America, because New England is the home of the Salem witch trials and has some really amazing Autum color, so it comes up in a Halloween Horror Movie often... Typically its where the townfolks keep their torches and pitchforks.  Tend to have a crusty old fishermen who scrape chalk boards as part of the offer to catch the nautical nightmare plaguing the town in the summer season.